how to query against a json column with key value pairs in mariadb
goal:
i need to create a query that finds the records that meet a given condition.
the condition is stored as JSON in sys_conditions column.
this is how the data is stored:
 SELECT sys_conditions FROM permissions WHERE sys_conditions IS NOT NULL;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sys_conditions                                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"column":"sys_active","value":true,"operator":"="},{"column":"sys_age","value":"[3,10]","operator":"between"}] |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

issue:
i am not able to figure out how to pull the record
example:
given sys_age of 5,
the query should pull the record above because the condition is between sys_age 3 and 10 but its not working.
is this even possible?
the conditions are saved in a json and i cant change that,
i can change the structure of the data in the json.
this was my best attempt::
SELECT *
FROM permissions
WHERE sys_conditions IS NOT NULL
  AND JSON_CONTAINS(sys_conditions, '{"column": "sys_age", "operator": "between"}', '$[*]') = 1
  AND JSON_EXTRACT(sys_conditions, '$[0].value') <= 5
  AND JSON_EXTRACT(sys_conditions, '$[1].value') >= 5;


What version of MariaDB do you have?

@PaulT. might be leading the same way, but look at this answer using json_table (10.6+)
